# How do I share data between pages on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm a newbie programmer, working on my first web app (using App Engine), so forgive my ignorance.

I have been modifying the Hello World program given by Google to try to make it do what I want.

In their demo (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html) they have 2 classes that create 2 pages - one is the index.html, and the other handles a form, by putting the form data into a DB, and then redirecting back to the main page, which loads info from the DB.

I would like to have a form on the main page where users submit a string, upon which various operations are performed, and the output is displayed on the main page.

The problem is that the data from the form submitted by users goes to the form handler page, and I can't figure out how to give the output back to the main page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The natural way to persist the data among different submits is by using the [Datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html).
If, for exercise, you don't want to use the datastore, you are forced to pass the data to the view and read it back using some `hidden` fields between each web request.

Let's see an easy *quick&dirty* example: a web app that sums integers one by one.

**application.py**

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class Sum(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        template_values = {"total":0}
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

    def post(self):    
        value = self.request.get("value")
        total = self.request.get("total")
        total = int(total) + int(value)
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        template_values = {"value":value,
                           "total":total
                          }
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                 [('/', Sum),
                                  ('/sum', Sum)],
                                 debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To pass the data to the `index.html` view, the template.render function is used passing a dictionary variable that carries the result to the view:

```
template.render(path_to_the_view, template_values)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="/sum" method="post">
    <p>
    <label for="value">Value to sum:
    <input type="text" name="value"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="total" value="{{ total }}">
    </p>
  </form>
  Last value submitted: {{ value }}| Total:{{ total }}
</body>
</html>
```

The `index.html` view uses the dictionary keys `value` and `total` to show the result and to submit back the total to the controller using an `hidden` field.

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Ah! I have a couple of questions.

1. Would it be possible to do this with 2 different classes? I noticed that you combined the 2 classes into one...

2. If you used the datastore to communicate across classes, how would that work? It seems like if user A submitted one value - say, "3", and submitted it, then total would equal 3, and you would store that in your datastore. Then, User B submitted 4, and it would return 7 for him, instead of 4, as expected. Would you also need to store a unique ID for each user?

Comment: @Jeremy 1) Yes - the handler class it's in doesn't matter. 2) That's exactly what the demo you're already looking at does.

Comment: @jeremy 1. You can organize your code in several Classes that fulfills your needs; it doesn't really matter. 2. In case you want to use the datastore in my naive example, yes, you should differentiate per user.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML form generated by the `index.html` template has the following `form` tag:

```
<form action="/sign" method="post">
```

This means the form's data will be sent to `/sign` when the user clicks the submit button.  The `action` URL determines which handler is used.  First, we look in your `app.yaml` file to see which script will be used to process the request:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

All URLs are handled by `helloworld.py`, so lets look there:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage),
                                      ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                                     debug=True)
```

Based on this, we can see that the `/sign` URL is handled by the `Guestbook` request handler.  If you wanted the form submission to be handled by a different page you would either need to change the page the form is being submitted to (the `action` attribute in the `form` tag) or change the request handler assigned to the specified.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't very clear. What I want is a way to use some output from the request handler on the main page. Is that possible, or should I just redirect the user to the request handler page (/sign, in this case)?

Comment: If you some output which should be generated on both your home and /sign pages, then perhaps you could refactor it into a separate function (outside of both request handlers, or as a static method on one of them) and call it from both.  Or perhaps you could use template inheritance to achieve this effect.  Depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am not understanding why you want to have the output back to the mainpage. On submitting the form the control goes to the handler class. Now you can use this form data in your requesthandler class in any way you want it to.

And if you want some data to be transferred from this requesthandler to your mainpage you create global variables or create another form with hidden inputs to transfer data. Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm wanting to do - sorry to be so ignorant, but how would I create a global variable and pass it back to the mainpage class, or create a form with hidden inputs and pass it back?

Comment: @Jeremy: See to create global variables you need to define it after the import statements like var1=None and in whichever functions you want to use it you have to define it like global var1. Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webapp.requestHandler, **request** is a dictionary object which contains all the data submitted by user. So, here is how you get the data

```
class SubmitHandler (webapp.RequestHandler):
  name = self.request.get ('name')
  email = self.request.get ('emil')
  # do whatever
```

This assumes that 'name' and 'email' are fields in your form.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an Ajax form, here is a link to a few examples (using jquery)
[jquery ajax form handling](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm)

Basically you define a form as you would do normally but instead of the post request sending you to another page, you post the request to a server handler which does something and passes back a response typically in json format which you can then process using javascript and update the main page with the results.