# How to pass DOM contents in request for the purpose of a Database lookup

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm building a learning project (using Python and Google App Engine) and have no idea how to do what I want. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

The project is a basic chore web application that can be seen live [here](http://chorestimemadison.appspot.com). As you can see, the Add Chore functionality works just fine. FYI, you have to reload the page in order to see the updated list of chores after you do add a chore. However, if you want to view the Details page of a chore, or even Complete a chore, you cannot yet do that in the app because I have yet to figure out how to reference the database entity in a way that makes sense leaving one page and going to another.

The updated project code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/madisongroupprojects/chorestime) for reference. Basically, what I am looking to do is when the user clicks on one of the "Do Chore" links, the app grabs a reference to the appropriate chore name and will then be able to do a Database lookup.

For example, grab a reference to "Dishes" and then the app can look up the chore data object that has the name "Dishes". Thank you in advance for your time and efforts.

Here is my main.py file...

```
import os
import re
from string import letters

import webapp2
import jinja2

from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape = True)

def render_str(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

class BlogHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        return render_str(template, **params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class ChoreFront(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        chores = db.GqlQuery("select * from Chore order by created desc limit 10")
        self.render('front.html', chores = chores)

class AddChore(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('add-chore.html')

    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('chore_name')
        description = self.request.get('chore_description')

        if name and description:
            # TODO - Implement error handling for duplicate chore 
            chore = Chore(parent = blog_key(), 
                          key_name = name,  
                          name = name, 
                          description = description, 
                          times_completed = 0, 
                          last_doer = "No one")
            chore.put()
            self.redirect('/')
        else:
            error = "Please provide a chore name and description!"
            self.render("add-chore.html", name = name, description = description, error=error)

class DoChore(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('do-chore.html')

    def post(self):
        doer_name = self.request.get('doer_name')

        if doer_name:
            # TODO - Update times_completed, last_doer, last_completed for the chore
            self.redirect('/')
        else:
            error = "Please enter your name!"
            self.render("do-chore.html", doer_name = doer_name, error=error)

class ChoreDetail(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('chore-detail.html')

    def post(self):
        doer_name = self.request.get('doer_name')

        if doer_name:
            # TODO - Update times_completed, last_doer, 
            # last_completed(done automatically) for the chore
            self.redirect('/')
        else:
            error = "Please enter your name!"
            self.render("do-chore.html", doer_name = doer_name, error=error)


def blog_key(name = 'default'):
    return db.Key.from_path('blogs', name)

class Chore(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    description = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    times_completed = db.IntegerProperty()
    last_doer = db.StringProperty()
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    last_completed = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)

    def render(self):
        self._render_text = self.description.replace('\n', '<br>')
        return render_str("chore.html", chore = self)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', ChoreFront), 
                               ('/addchore', AddChore),
                               ('/dochore', DoChore), 
                               ('/choredetail', ChoreDetail)
                                ], 
                                debug=True)
```

Comment: How do I do that abstractly in code so that it refers to that dom element for any "Do Chore" link clicked? Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Could you give me an example in code? Would I need JavaScript for that?

Comment: Would you like put your answer as an answer so I may accept it as correct and give you credit for it?

Comment: I have way better. I'll delete my other comments and give you this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414936/how-do-i-share-data-between-pages-on-google-app-engine . and no need for rep, since this would fall under being a duplicate anyway ^^

Comment: also, this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391026/google-app-engine-request-class-query-string